# Put data in Gson and display it in a listview

Tags: android, json, listview, gson

It's my first time face to face with **Gson**. My question will be a long one, hope you'll understand and I there are more problems which got me stuck for about 1 week.

So, I have a `ListView` where I get selected items from another `Activity`. Under this `ListView` I have a `Button` where the seller save items to `FireBase`, bought by customer.

Now the problem is, each time when seller save bought items to `FireBase` I want to enumerate(like an increment) each customer and give a **customer number**. And show the number of customer in `TextView` in top of the page where number 1 is in the picture. But next day enumeration have to starts from 1. So every day has to starts from 1.
In this `ListView`, I am counting selected items and calculate sum of prices.

[image]

But second problem is I have no idea how to send **customer number**, **counted items** and **sum of items** to another `ListView` with a card view. I want to put it inside of Gson. I tried something, but I'm completely lost. And my code looks really messy in this moment. Hope you'll understand.

Here is the code where I get selected items and display **counted items** and **sum of items** with Toast:

```
int totalPrice = 0;
            for(VanzatorProduse v : Util.getInstance().getVanzatorProduse())
            {
                int vPrice = Integer.parseInt(v.getPret());
                totalPrice = totalPrice + vPrice;
            }

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Selected products : " + listaProdusePreview.getAdapter().getCount() +"\n"+"Total sum : " + totalPrice , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            Intent sumaProduse = new Intent(FormCumparareActivity.this, VanzatorActivity.class);
            sumaProduse.putExtra("sumaProduse", totalPrice);
            startActivity(sumaProduse);

            String produseSelectate = String.valueOf(listaProdusePreview.getAdapter().getCount());
            Intent intent = new Intent(FormCumparareActivity.this, VanzatorActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("produseSelectate", produseSelectate);
            startActivity(intent);

            Util.getInstance().getVanzatorProduse().removeAll(Util.getInstance().getVanzatorProduse());
```

Object class for **customer number**, **counted items** and **sum of items** :

```
public class Card {
private Integer numarCumparator;
private String listaProduse;
private Integer sumaProduse;

public Card(Integer numarCumparator, String listaProduse, Integer sumaProduse) {
    this.numarCumparator = numarCumparator;
    this.listaProduse = listaProduse;
    this.sumaProduse = sumaProduse;
}

public Integer getNumarCumparator() {
    return numarCumparator;
}

public void setNumarCumparator(Integer numarCumparator) {
    this.numarCumparator = numarCumparator;
}

public String getListaProduse() {
    return listaProduse;
}

public void setListaProduse(String listaProduse) {
    this.listaProduse = listaProduse;
}

public Integer getSumaProduse() {
    return sumaProduse;
}

public void setSumaProduse(Integer sumaProduse) {
    this.sumaProduse = sumaProduse;
}
```

Here is code for listview adapter:

```
public class CardArrayAdapter  extends ArrayAdapter<Card> {
private static final String TAG = "CardArrayAdapter";
private List<Card> cardList = new ArrayList<Card>();

static class CardViewHolder {
    TextView line1;
    TextView line2;
    TextView line3;
}

public CardArrayAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId) {
    super(context, textViewResourceId);
}

@Override
public void add(Card object) {
    cardList.add(object);
    super.add(object);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return this.cardList.size();
}

@Override
public Card getItem(int index) {
    return this.cardList.get(index);
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View row = convertView;
    CardViewHolder viewHolder;
    if (row == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_card, parent, false);
        viewHolder = new CardViewHolder();
        viewHolder.line1 = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.txtViewNumarCumparator);
        viewHolder.line2 = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.listaProduse);
        viewHolder.line3 = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.sumaProduse);
        row.setTag(viewHolder);
    } else {
        viewHolder = (CardViewHolder)row.getTag();
    }
    Card card = getItem(position);

        viewHolder.line1.setText(card.getNumarCumparator());
        viewHolder.line2.setText(card.getListaProduse());
        viewHolder.line3.setText(card.getSumaProduse());

    return row;
}
```

Layout for card view:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:descendantFocusability="afterDescendants"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="15dp"
    android:paddingLeft="15dp"
    android:paddingRight="15dp"
    android:paddingTop="15dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtViewNumarCumparator"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="NumarCumparator" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/listaProduse"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txtViewNumarCumparator"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:text="NumarProduse" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/sumaProduse"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:text="SumaProdsue" />
```

Here, is my attempt for Gson, I put it in a JSONManager class:

```
    public class JSONManager {

private static JSONManager instance = null;



protected JSONManager() {
    // Exists only to defeat instantiation.
}

public static JSONManager getInstance() {
    if (instance == null) {
        instance = new JSONManager();
    }
    return instance;
}


//Create list of Cards because we need to show list for date selected
public List<Card> readJSON(String dateFromCalendar) throws JSONException {

    String JSON = SharedPreference.getString(Util.get(), SharedPreference.APP_DATA, SharedPreference.JSON_DATA, "");
    String numeVanzator = SharedPreference.getString(Util.get(), SharedPreference.USER_DATA, SharedPreference.NUME_VANZATOR,"");

    JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(JSON);

    JSONArray contacts = jsonObj.getJSONArray("jsonData");
    List<Card> listCard = null;
    Card card = null;

    listCard = new ArrayList<>();


    for (int i =0; i< contacts.length();i++) {

        JSONObject c = contacts.getJSONObject(i);
        String data = c.getString("data");

        if (data.equals(dateFromCalendar)){
            String numeVanzato = c.getString("numeVanzator");
            if (numeVanzato.equals(numeVanzator)){

                Integer numarClient = c.getInt("numarClient");

                JSONObject detaliiCos = c.getJSONObject("detaliiCos");
                Integer sumaProduse = detaliiCos.getInt("sumaProduse");
                String produseselectate = c.getString("produseSelectate");

                card = new Card(numarClient, produseselectate, sumaProduse);
                listCard.add(card);
            }
        }
    }
    return listCard;
}  }
```

Code for activity where I tried to get data inside from Gson.

```
   @Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    c = Calendar.getInstance();
    String numeVanzator = SharedPreference.getString(this, SharedPreference.USER_DATA, SharedPreference.NUME_VANZATOR, "");
    if (!numeVanzator.equals("")) {
        textViewNumeVanzator.setText(numeVanzator);
    }


   String jsonData = SharedPreference.getString(getApplicationContext(), SharedPreference.APP_DATA, SharedPreference.JSON_DATA, "");

    System.out.println("JSON data" + jsonData);

   textViewDataCurenta.setText(getDate(c.getTimeInMillis()));

    cardArrayAdapter = new CardArrayAdapter(this, R.layout.list_item_card);

   Card card = null;
    List<Card> listCard = new ArrayList<Card>();
    c = Calendar.getInstance();

    try {
        String date = getDate(c.getTimeInMillis());
        listCard = JSONManager.getInstance().readJSON(date);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    for (int i = 0; i <= listCard.size()-1; i++) {

       card = listCard.get(i);
        cardArrayAdapter.add(card);
    }
    listViewVanzatorActivity.setAdapter(cardArrayAdapter);
}
```

Right now, everything is working perfectly but when click on save `Button` nothing appears in next activity and no errors.

Hope, you understand my question, I really need your help. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In your code you created two times Intent for call activity that is not good way.
just remove second intent from this

```
 Intent sumaProduse = new Intent(FormCumparareActivity.this, VanzatorActivity.class);
 sumaProduse.putExtra("sumaProduse", totalPrice);
 startActivity(sumaProduse);


 Intent intent = new Intent(FormCumparareActivity.this, VanzatorActivity.class);
 intent.putExtra("produseSelectate", produseSelectate);
 startActivity(intent);
```

now create new bundle and add pass to this with key like this:

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(FormCumparareActivity.this, VanzatorActivity.class);
 Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
 bundle.put("key",totalPrice);
 bundle.put("key",produseSelectate);
 intent .putExtras(bundle)
 startActivity(intent);
```

you are getting list from JSON which are not store in shared preferences.
hope you are get it my point.